# OctoberCMS, how to define relationship with children model?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I need render children model in template, my parent model "Form" haves db field "field_id", where field_id equals id children model "Field". How can I access the child model? I tried add relation to Field model:

```
public $hasOne = [
        'field' => ['\Webfather\Services\Models\Variation', 'key' => 'field_id']
    ];
```

and tried display in template:

```
{{form.field.name}}
```

but form.field was empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your relation linking is wrong.

what you need to do is, you need to define `form_id`  inside your child model(`Variation`)

you need to insert form_id => 'parent model (`Form`) id' there

then inside `Form` model

```
public $hasOne = [
    'field' => ['\Webfather\Services\Models\Variation', 'key' => 'form_id']
];
```

so now it will search child model(`Variation`) where `form_id` = `id` of parent `Form`

and then you can get child record.

### OR to make it working with current scenario you need to make `Form` model as child. (less code changes)

then inside `Form` model

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'field' => ['\Webfather\Services\Models\Variation', 'key' => 'field_id']
];
```

now you can use

```
{{form.field.name}}
```